# Bad operand types for binary operator '<=' java error

Tags: java

```
while ((1 <= arr[i] <= arr.length) && (arr[i] != arr[correctPos])) {
```

Why am I getting the error in this line of code?

Comment: You need to pud && after arr[i]

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a double inequality expression like this in Java (or really most programming languages).  Use this version:

```java
while ((1 <= arr[i] && arr[i] <= arr.length) && (arr[i] != arr[correctPos])) {
    // ...
}
```